# Too slow to unzip dataset in google colab from google drive

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, google-colaboratory, unzip

I have my dataset which is around 1.2GB and want to upload it on google colab. What I tried is, I compressed the dataset into zip and it turned 479MB. Then upload the zip file into google drive, and do the folloing command in google colab.

`!unzip Archive.zip`

It starts to unzip the file but it's too slow(I've waited for three hours but it didn't finish). I'm using GPU of google colab and smaller zip file was unzipped correctly. Is there faster way to upload dataset on google colab?

Comment: Ever figured it out?

Comment: same problem for me